# I cannot import pymc3

Tags: python, pymc3

I cannot import pymc3, after installation I get the error message below. Based on  issues others noted I installed
!pip install pymc3,
conda install m2w64-toolchain,
conda install theano

I get the same error message when attempting to import theano as well. "ImportError: cannot import name 'is_same_graph' from 'theano.gof.toolbox"

```
import pymc3 as pm
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-2e5c536b7c65>", line 1, in <module>
    import pymc3 as pm

  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    __set_compiler_flags()

  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\__init__.py", line 33, in __set_compiler_flags
    import theano

  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (

  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function import function, function_dump

  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function.pfunc import pfunc

  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function\pfunc.py", line 10, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function.types import UnusedInputError, orig_function

  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function\types.py", line 23, in <module>
    from theano.gof.toolbox import is_same_graph

ImportError: cannot import name 'is_same_graph' from 'theano.gof.toolbox' (C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\toolbox.py)
```

Comment: Check your PYTHONPATH

Comment: demonstrate my ignorance here but what do you mean?

Comment: The PYTONPATH is the path that Python looks for to import your dependencies.

Comment: Simply do: sys.path

Comment: (you need to import sys first)

Comment: Look at each of those directories. Do you see pymc3 in any of those dirs?

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to ensure you have the correct version of the [Theano-PyMC](https://github.com/pymc-devs/theano-pymc) fork of `Theano` installed. You may also need to remove an overlapping installation of the original `Theano`. At this time it looks like `PyMC3 3.10.0` is constrained to install with `Theano-PyMC 1.0.11`. You may find that

```sh
conda remove theano
pip uninstall Theano Theano-PyMC PyMC3
pip install PyMC3
```

would fix your issue. If not, you may need to remove the theano directory. On a *nix system, depending on your configuration, this could be in `/usr/lib` so you might need to run an analog of

```sh
sudo rm -fr /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/theano/
```

relevant to your Windows system in between the uninstall and reinstall. There may be other issues that arise because of the interaction between anaconda and pip.